# running winrm set winrm/config/Service '@{AllowUnencrypted="true"}' give Error number: -2147024894 0x80070002

Tags: winrm, windows-server-2019, powershell-5.1

running the command: winrm set winrm/config/Service '@{AllowUnencrypted="true"}'
on Windows server 2019, give the fallowing error:

```
WSManFault
Message
    ProviderFault
        WSManFault
            Message = The system cannot find the file specified.

Error number:  -2147024894 0x80070002
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

We are trying to figure this out, 2 people, searching the internet, not finding nothing...

OPlease, if anyone have any idea, at least to point us in the proper search direction, it would be very very appreciated...

Thank you so much !!!

Comment: Not an answer, but PLEASE for your security's sake, find a way to make this work WITH encrypted traffic.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by opening advance windows firewall, clicked exported rules (just in case), and then click restore to default. (Note this will enable the firewall profiles and could block RDP access or interfere with your applications). Afterwards the errors stopped. Hope that does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
stop-service "Windows Firewall"
 winrm set winrm/config/Service '@{AllowUnencrypted="true"}'
start-service "Windows Firewall"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).